# How can i display unique fields in mysql result after join multiple tables with same field names?

Tags: mysql, join, unique, alias

Following query joining 3 tables:

```
select * from product_group_pids as pgp  

join product_group_attributes pga on pga.group_id=pgp.group_id

join product_group_attribute_values pgav on pgav.group_id=pgp.group_id

where pgp.group_id = (219138)
```

In all 3 tables group_id exits, Result will show 3 times the same group_id. How can i restrict to display only once? Making alias names does not make sense to specify explicitly for multiple fields in tables. Can i get any suggestions to restrict with join statements?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `NATURAL JOIN` or `USING` instead of `ON`. This will fold both used columns into one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found some alternatives:

```
MySQL joins: ON vs. USING vs. Theta-style


SELECT * FROM film JOIN film_actor ON (film.film_id = film_actor.film_id)
**SELECT * FROM film JOIN film_actor USING (film_id)**
SELECT * FROM film, film_actor WHERE film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
```

Resource:[here](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysql-joins-on-vs-using-vs-theta-style)
I think it will help some one...